# while using azure form recognizer for medical prescription some key value pair(like no of quantity and refills ) are not getting extracted

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

while using azure form recognizer for medical prescription some key-value pair(like no of quantity and refills ) are not getting extracted.

How can we extract that thing? or we have to use any other machine learning library to do that.

The problem is we have one form and we have created 5 samples out of it for azure form recognizer.

the form is in  .tiff format.

no. of refills is usually written as -
n refills, refills n, refills 1,2,3,4,5.

Example: “Odefsey 200-25-25 mg tabs TAKE ONE TABLET BY MOUTH ONCE DAILY. #90 tabs, 3 Refills needs to be broken into

1. ```
     Drug Name: Odefsey
   ```
2. ```
     Strength: 200-25-25 mg
   ```
3. ```
     Dosage Form: tabs
   ```
4. ```
     Directions: ONE TABLET BY MOUTH ONCE DAILY
   ```
5. ```
     Quantity: 90
   ```
6. ```
     Refills: 3
   ```

Quantity and Refills are not recognized by Azure text analytics for Health

[We have to extract refills from below pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSXdO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the latest Form Recognizer release and see if it resolves the issue - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/whats-new
You can try it out in the Form Recognizer sample tool - https://fott-preview.azurewebsites.net/